# Rationale behind storing XML in a relational Database

Tags: xml, oracle, sql-server-2008

I need to explain why we need to store XML documents in a database.

On the up side:

1. No effort to shred individual elements to tables and atrribute to columns
2. No effort to maintain relations between tables as they are self contained within XML
3. Portable across systems that share the XML
4. Should there be a need, literally all DBMS support XML operations to query XML as a relational entity.

On the down side:

1. Network payload considerably larger than the RDBMS counter part.
2. Require client applications to shred them to usable components.

Are these justifications valid? Can anyone think of any more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a definitive pro con list - its dependent on what you're trying to do. But here are a couple more for you to think about:

1. Not all SQL databases support XML xpath (beyond `blob like '%xxx%'`). Perhaps you are stuck on an older version of a database, which doesn't have XML support functions (ie, Mysql 4). Lighter SQL databases such as Sqlite and hsql would also fall into this camp.
2. Even when XML can be searched in the database, its not optimal. SQL searches of XML can't take advantage of the SQL server's built in search optimizations (ie, indexes).
3. Depending on the database you use the XML document in the database also cannot take advantage of the SQL server's validation and type features. For instance Oracle can do XML schema validation, and I don't see that Mysql can.
4. Performance for what queries you can do, won't compare to standard column queries.
5. Database size. If you store XML in your database its going to be bigger. You could compress it, but then querying it would be hard/impossible.
6. [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) issues may become relevant issues - perhaps you don't expect to use SQL to query the XML at some point, but then at a later point its decided that some field is actually needed. You may need to pull that field out of the XML and populate an actual column just to get the desired performance...in which case you now have redundant information in your database.

The pros and cons really depend on what you are going to be storing, and what its for.

1. If its essentially binary/configuration information that you just need to stick some place, and for whatever reason prefer to stick in your SQL database...well, considerations regarding queries aren't relevant. In that case, the important issues would concern space and how to minimize it (ie, compression).
2. If there is any possibility that the XML would need to be searched regularly then you run the risk of slow queries and the redundancy issues I mentioned above. In which case, you should consider your *long term* design very carefully up front: do you really need to store this data as XML? Would it be better to construct XML from that data?

Answer (score 3):

There are pro and cons in both cases and it depends on your usage scenario.

The main disadvantages of storing as XML itself is that we wont be able to perform a quick search for a particular data. To perform a search, we will have to retrieve and parse all the XML files.

We encountered a similar situation in one of our projects. After discussing over it, we went in for a middle ground approach:
All the main information (information that needs to be quickly queried) were stored in related tables. And we stored the XMLs also; but instead of storing the XML as such, we saved the XML to disk and used that file path in the table.

Answer (score 3):

Discussing your comments:

1. Not storing individual elements also means not enforcing the constraints on them
2. Again, constraints between tables are not stored
3. Only portable if the target system confirms to the same schema.
4. Yes but the performance will vary.